# No overfitting but bad prediction

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, classification, python, image-processing

I classified some medical images. And distribution of the dataset is :

494 Train Anormal

469 Train Normal

37 Test Normal

64 Test Anormal

84 Val Anormal

37 Val Normal

...

My training result is (by ViT):

loss: 0.2714 - accuracy: 0.9102 - val_loss: 0.2624 - val_accuracy: 0.9196

and test result is:

```
               precision    recall    f1-score   support

           0       0.57      0.60      0.58        47
           1       0.46      0.43      0.44        37

    accuracy                           0.52        84

   macro avg       0.51      0.51      0.51        84

weighted avg       0.52      0.52      0.52        84
```

- So my question is that test prediction is not good because of
  imbalanced data?  Or I should figure out something else?

I know 1000 images are not a nice thing in DL but I have to complete this training with them. Also, I implemented data augmentation.

Comment: A couple possibilities - (1) you have been using validation extensively to optimize hyperparameters, and thus it is effectively just part of your training set; (2) test data just looks different from training/validation

Comment: 1. I didn't understand your first comment, 2. Do you mean the size of the test is different?

Comment: On what basis did you state "no overfitting" in the title?

Comment: @ZehraN. please be more specific about the part you did not understand. We are not being paid to help you. It is frustrating to hear "I didn't understand" without any explanation and makes people less inclined to help you.

Comment: The problem is that the training set is approximately balanced, but your test and validation sets have significantly fewer normal than anormal examples, which is why the classifier is presumably over-predicting "normal" in the test set (difficult to tell because of the labelling).  Your training set should be representative of the statistical distribution in the test set (and in operation), and that includes the relative frequencies of the classes.  You might want to use stratified resampling to form the training, test and validation sets, so they all have the same label distributions.

Comment: @ChristianHennig you can see the Val acc and training acc.

Comment: @Paul question is so clear. test prediction results are not nice. But my model is not bad. ?

Comment: @DikranMarsupial thank you so much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be some difference between the training/validation and the testing data, causing performance gap.
Another potential cause is that you tuned your model heavily on the validation set.
This might make the model overfit to the validation set.

Comment: Thank you. But how should I fix the validation set? Size, distribution?--I didn't understand this:  " heavily on the validation set. "

Comment: Sorry for my poor English. What I mean is that you might use the validation set to tune the hyperparameters too much. And I think you can first investigate the training/validation/testing sets. For example, plotting these sets in low dimensional space to check their distribution. If the testing set is too different from training/validation sets, then the low testing accuracy is not the model's fault. Or you can merge training and validation set together, and use k-fold cross validation on them. This would give you more robust results.

Comment: Got it. Thank you